# Redirect domain to Openshift page

Tags: redirect, dns, openshift, paas

I want to redirect my domain.com to openshift page (openshift-app.rhcloud.com). I've done it as described [here](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/custom-url-names-for-your-paas-applications-host-forwarding-and-cnames-the-openshift-way) and it works. The only problem is that on any site I won't be the address will always be `domain.com`. For example:

```
openshift-app.rhcloud.com -> domain.com
openshift-app.rhcloud.com/site1 -> domain.com
openshift-app.rhcloud.com/site2/subsite1 -> domain.com
```

All of those sites will redirect to `domain.com`. Is there any possibility to redirect it in a 'normal' way where entire address will be shown?

Comment: This is good advice: http://www.tamingthebeast.net/articles3/spiders-301-redirect.htm
What you are doing is a so called masked redirect. You want a 'normal' 301 redirect in your access file.

Comment: I've added permanent redirection (301) but after redirection from `domain.com` address is changed to `openshift-app.rhcloud.com`. I don't want it to be changed.

Comment: Ok I get it now. It wasn't clear for me from your description.
Check out this link http://www.ehow.com/how_8538343_cloak-url-redirect.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally resolved the problem. All I had to do:

Add aliases to openshift page (for www.mydomain.com and mydomain.com)

Add those rules to domain

```
mydomain.com.   A   <ip_address_to_openshift_page>
www             A   <ip_address_to_openshift_page>
mydomain.com.   NS  <dns_of_domain_provider>
```

For example (my domain is on linuxpl.com):

```
mydomain.com.   A   107.22.142.72
www             A   107.22.142.72   
mydomain.com.   NS  ns15.linuxpl.com.
```

Answer (score 2):

Add rule to .htaccess with 301 redirect for mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^openshift-app.rhcloud.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Specifically for cartridge python-2.6 in folder ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/wsgi/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^openshift-app.rhcloud.com$
RewriteRule ^application/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```